# Blazor Webassembly Azure AD authentication hosted in Azure storage account

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-storage, blazor-webassembly

According to instruction described in “Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory” https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1 I have created the simplest blazor webassembly app.
At https://portal.azure.com I registered new app in AAD and based on generated GUIDs generated local app with this command:

> dotnet new blazorwasm -au SingleOrg --client-id "{CLIENT ID}"
> --tenant-id "{TENANT ID}" -o {APP NAME}

Everything worked fine if I launched app locally. If I copied published app to storage account $web and try to log in I have received:

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the
> reply URLs configured for the application: '…'.

During app registration I have defined app as “Web” and put Redirect URL:
https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback
I have tried different combinations of URL changing hostname, deleting port and changing path. I don’t know how to successfully configure app in AD.

Comment: Navigate to your storage account in the portal -> `Static website` -> copy the `Primary endpoint`, then change the redirect url with `<Primary endpoint>/authentication/login-callback`, something like `https://xxxx.z13.web.core.windows.net/authentication/login-callback`, will it work?

Comment: I have changed Redirect URL as you suggested and after clicking login link server answered "The requested content does not exist.

HttpStatusCode: 404
ErrorCode: WebContentNotFound
RequestId : 59d63c65-a01e-00d7-7827-5c8b94000000
TimeStamp : 2020-07-17T10:43:11.6487124Z"

Comment: If so, the original issue was solved, for the new issue, you need to specify an error document when you enabled the website, then a default 404 page is returned to the user, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#setting-up-a-static-website

Comment: Original issue was not solved. Problem is the same: HTTP server cannot find landing place (Redirect URL) after user was logged. I have just read source code of authentication library. Everything looks fine so the problem is in other place.

Comment: Could you show your request url when user login?

Comment: (https://...web.core.windows.net/authentication/login)

Comment: I mean the request url you used to get the token.

Comment: I had the same issue and but @JoyWang's 2nd comment solved it (you need to specify *index.html* as the error document, too).

Answer (score 0):

The AAD error states that the URL which you are getting redirected is not present in the reply url list configured in the app registration.You need to register a reply url in the format -  {WebsiteUrl}/authentication/login-callback.
Please give it a try then hopefully should resolve the issue.
**Note-WebsiteUrl is the Url hosted in azure**

Comment: I have tried this localhost and full site name. It does not work.

Comment: @MarekSłowikowski - what i meant is that {WebsiteUrl}/authentication/login-callback should be registered as a reply URL in your azure active active directory app registration(authentication blade).Whatever you use as a redirect uri in your app should be exactly similar to the one registered in reply URL's in AAD.

Comment: @MarekSłowikowski-when your application is getting redirected to azure active active directory you will be getting an url in format -https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910 can you please let know what is the redirect uri the application is passing in url?

Comment: I have just read static sites created on Azure Storage Account does not supports CORS. Azure App Service does so the same static site cited with Azure App Service works fine.

Comment: @MarekSłowikowski -  Glad to know that authentication is working on your static website deployed in an app service , You can take a look at azure app service for static websites(preview) which has been built primarily for static websites and might as well suit your needs better.Strange because storage accounts support cors so therefore  static website hosted in storage accounts should support cors i will investigate further on this issue and update you if i find anything useful.

Comment: @MarekSłowikowski - If you can clarify on the following question it will be really helpful for me - Did you changed any configuration before deploying your app to app service ? If yes would be really helpful to know what was that ?

Comment: No, I did not. I have published the same copy to Azure storage account static iwebsite and to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers and comments above, I took me 2 steps to solve this:

1. Azure AD must have an entry in **App registration | Authentication |  Single-page application | Redirect URIs** that reads `{WebsiteUrl}/authentication/login-callback`. `{WebsiteUrl}` comes from the **Storage account | Static website |     Primary endpoint**.
2. Make sure that **Storage account | Static website | Index document name**
   *and* **Error document path** *both* point to `index.html`.